# Maven - Parent Pom - Child Inheritance

Tags: maven

I am attempting to make a maven parent pom setup where I don't have to declare any plugin information in my child pom, everything is taken from the parent pom.

I essentially have it working where I've put all my plugins with there configurations in to the parent pom.  Then in the child poms I have to declare the plugin still, but without the version and configuration information.

I don't want to have to declare the plugin in the child at all.  This way I can add new features (such as pmd, freebugs, etc) to my parent pom and all my projects now have them working.  How can I accomplish this?

Parent Pom

```xml
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <providerImplementations>
                    <cvs>cvs_native</cvs>
                </providerImplementations>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>maven.scm.perforce.clientspec.name</name>
                        <value>${perforceClientSpec}</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Child Pom still needs this but I don't want to have to do this if I can avoid it:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`<pluginManagement>` section is intended to configure project builds that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that are **actually** referenced within the plugins element in the children (so you have to explicitly specify them, as you indicated). See more [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management).

If you want to avoid this, you can put this information into `<build>` section like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <...>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <...>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: @Nishant explains further why this works.  Plugins declared outside of `<pluginManagement>` are inherited by child POMs, by default.  Their settings can be overridden by each child if desired.  Plugins declared within `<pluginManagement>` configure global settings for all child POMs that explicitly are configured to consume those plugins (as in the original example).  Their settings may also be overridden within the child POMs.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov @hotshot309 @Nishant, when placing in `<build> <plugins>` as mentioned in your answers, when the child pom overrides it by declaring the plugin with its own `<configuration>` & `<executions>` BUT without mentioning the plugin `<version>` in the child pom does it then inherit/resolve the version to the one mentioned in the parent pom or does it default to the latest?

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using `pluginManagement`, try using just [`<plugins>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) tag. It should be auto inherited. You may optionally override configuration in child pom. Check that by `mvn help:effective-pom`

Comment: its sad the effective-pom doesn't show the plugin's default binding phase

Comment: @Nishant, when placing in `<plugins>` as mentioned in your answer, when the child pom overrides it by declaring the plugin with its own `<configuration>` & `<executions>` BUT without mentioning the plugin `<version>` in the child pom does it then inherit/resolve the version to the one mentioned in the parent pom or does it default to the latest?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid naming the plugin in the child pom, cause how should maven know which plugin are you using. The pluginManagement section is intended for defining the versions of plugin furthermore it's used to define a default configuration.