# How to reference a parent project from a child

Tags: maven

I have a multi module project like this:

- gwt-app
- model
- webapp (depends on gwt-app and model)

when I try to execute any goals in webapps, for example, launch jetty, build fails because maven can't find its dependencies (I didn't install modules into a local repo). Is there a possible way to reference the parent pom so that when I run any goals in a submodule, all its dependencies will be compiled (recompiled)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of your pom files would be great but in multi module projects I always declare the dependencies in the parent pom in the dependencyManagement tag:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
...
```

In the module pom I just delcare the dependency without the version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>group-a</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

That way were are sure each module uses the same version.

The thing to remember is that modules in maven do not inherit dependencies from the parent.  You must declare the dependencies used in the module itself.

Another thing is, I believe that when you are running outside of an IDE (which searches the workspace for dependencies) you need to have each module installed in your local repo.  I do not think maven will search for un-installed dependencies within a multi module project if you are not executing on the parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your parent pom just have regular setup like

```
<plugins>
</plugins>
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
```

Then anything in those groups are inherited automatically into the child pom.  Child pom just needs the parent section in it:

```
<parent>
</parent>
```

You don't even need to declare the same plugins or dependencies in the child pom in this manner.  You only need to list the plugins or dependencies in the child pom IF you use  or  in the parent pom OR you want to override something in the parent pom.  I actually just went through all of this week and have my builds working nicely now (small child poms with more things in the parent pom like plugin configurations).

I asked a question about this that might help you:
[Maven - Parent Pom - Child Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477789/maven-parent-pom-child-inheritance)