# Weird behavior with Maven plugin management with maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent pom which defines

```html
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
                        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

I have a child project which inherits from the pom but does not declare the plugin in its plugin section.
I am still seeing the plugin take effect when I run maven test goal.

Comment: Does the Pom refer to its parent? Where do you run mvn?

Comment: yes. The child project refers to its parent. I run the maven goal inside the child module root folder.

Comment: If it refers to its parent it picks up configuration from there.

Comment: When refering the maven documentation. https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management. It says the child module has to explicitly reference the plugin for it to work.

Comment: Also I infered the same form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477789/maven-parent-pom-child-inheritance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When defining maven-surefire plugin in the parent project
Refer:http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/usage.html

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.1</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Adding the configuration section causes it to execute in each of the child projects implicitly.

In the child project the configuration will look like

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
      <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
      <threadCount>4</threadCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Even though the configuration in the child project is quite verbose, it ensures explicit addition of the dependency and the same version of the plugin in all sub-modules.

Comment: Not sure what this answer explains. When you say "child project is quite verbose", are you talking about manually adding the plugin to the child? If yes, then you shouldn't need to do this. You shouldn't even need to declare anything about the plugin in the child project. All of the configuration in the `pluginManagement` should be inherited from the parent automatically. And this answer does not say why this inheritance is done.

Comment: Any any configuration in `plugin` section gets inherited automatically. Any configuration in `pluginManagement` section only gets added when explicitly specified in the plugin section of the child project. The advantage defining the config in `pluginmanagement` is the fact that all sub modules use the same plugin version.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal because the `maven-surefire-plugin` is by default bound to the `test` phase as part of the [built-in lifecycle bindings](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings). No need to declare it in the child project.

In other words, the plugin is implicitly available to the child project because it binds itself to the `test` phase. The `maven-scm-plugin` (linked in the other question) is not bound by default to any phase so you have to declare it in the child to inherit the configuration from the parent. But because `maven-surefire-plugin` is bound by default to the test phase, you don't need to declare it in the child. Try running `mvn help:effective-pom` in your child module to see the *effective POM* which shows the final POM that Maven actually uses. Check http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html to see the default plugin bindings.

If you want to skip the plugin, just execute `mvn install` or pass `-DskipTests=true`. If you still need to run `mvn test` to run tests in other projects, you can skip tests in the child module's POM (although this is not recommended at all):

```
<plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
              <skipTests>true</skipTests>
         </configuration>
     </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Can you please have look at the two comments I added on the question?

Comment: @Shibashis The example in the linked question features a plugin that _has_ to be declared in the child. However, for plugins like `maven-surefire-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin`, they are already bound to build phases by default. I would say the documentation could be improved to add this note. To also confirm this, the [plugin's doc](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) mentions this: "Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: test."

Comment: I understand the plugin binds itself to the test phase. But my question is why is the plugin becoming available in the child project implicitly.

Comment: From the documentation and the stackoverflow question content it seems otherwise.

Comment: @Shibashis The plugin is implicitly available to the child project _because_ it binds itself to the test phase. The `maven-scm-plugin` plugin (linked in the other question) is not bound by default to any phase so you have to declare it in the child to inherit the configuration from the parent. But because `maven-surefire-plugin` is bound by default to the test phase, you don't need to declare it in the child. Try running `mvn help:effective-pom` in your child module to see the effective POM which  shows the final POM that Maven actually uses.

Comment: I think, i figured it out for maven-surefire plugin. Let me post that as answer.